# The surreal numbers under a change of universe

Tags: set-theory, model-theory, large-cardinals, axioms, surreal-numbers

Suppose we start with a model $\mathcal{M}$ of $ZFC$ (or $GBC$ or $MK$ if you prefer), and let $N_0^\mathcal{M}$ denote the surreals in $\mathcal{M}$.  If we add some large cardinal assumptions $\{\phi_i\}_{i<\alpha}$ to $ZFC$ and produce a new theory $T=ZFC+\{\phi_i\}_{i<n}$ with $\mathcal{N}$ a model of $T$ such that $\mathcal{M}$ is a transitive model of $ZFC$ in $\mathcal{N}$ not satisfying $\{\phi_i\}_{i<n}$, we might* obtain new cardinals and ordinals in $\mathcal{N}$ not in $\mathcal{M}$ which in turn yield new surreal numbers in $N_0^\mathcal{N}$.

Has this been studied at all/is it obvious to someone here how to deal with this when trying to study the surreals? In particular I wonder about new algebraic/topological/categorical/(someday) analytical properties of $N_0^\mathcal{N}$ in comparison with $N_0^\mathcal{M}$.

For example, if $T=ZFC+\text{there exists a weakly inaccessible cardinal}$ then $N_0^\mathcal{N}$ has a natural value class  "larger" than $N_0^\mathcal{M}$ since each new inaccessible introduced yields a new possible value. As mentioned below the model theory of $N_0$ when only paying attention to its arithmetic operations is characterized entirely by it being real-closed, but a value class is additional data and Andreas Blass brings up the excellent question of what additional data on the surreals would allow them to interpret the whole set theoretical universe.

I'm currently worrying about much smaller cardinals (equivalent to Grothendieck universes) for the purpose of letting the Surreals be an object in the category ${\bf CRing}$ -- note here that not only is the class of objects in ${\bf CRing}$ a proper class, some of the objects themselves are also proper classes in an 'uninitiated' universe.

It seems that we're 'changing' the surreals when we introduce the standard additional large cardinal axioms used in category theory for dealing with proper classes; is this true, and if so how can we understand the changes in a precise manner?

My intuition says that there is an answer along the lines of 'restrict to a certain size surreals and use those', but ideally I would like to work with a version of the surreals containing all known large cardinals to see what they look like, so a more general methodology is desirable.

*as was pointed out in the comments by Andrés E. Caicedo and Noah Schweber, it is possible for $\mathcal{N}$ to retain all ordinals and lose cardinals in this situation if the submodel $\mathcal{M}$ is an inner model and has fewer surjections between small ordinals and larger ones, but I'm not sure the surreals 'care' whether an ordinal is a cardinal or not.

Comment: " If we add some large cardinal assumptions ... we obtain new cardinals and ordinals in the new universe " What? No, we don't. Also, I do not understand this idea of a "new" universe. That's not how strengthening a set of axioms works.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo I am not an expert here, apologies for any inaccuracies.  I thought that, for example, $ZFC$ can't prove the existence of an inaccessible cardinal so if we assume one exists we have a new cardinal in the universe. What am I missing here?  For the 'new universe' bit my understanding was that each collection of set theoretical axioms has some collection of classes it can prove are sets, which forms the universe determined by those axioms, and adding more axioms allows us to prove that more classes are actually sets (like the infinity axiom) and 'put them in the universe'.

Comment: A universe satisfying ZFC + "there is an inaccessible cardinal" is, in particular, a universe satisfying ZFC. (Adding more axioms doesn't make the old ones false.) So whatever you might have proved about the surreal numbers using ZFC is still correct when you make the additional assumption that an inaccessible cardinal exists.

Comment: @AndreasBlass But what about the other direction? If I prove something about the surreals in a universe with inaccessibles or larger cardinals it might fail to be provable in the base universe and false in some other extension correct?

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo If this question is incoherent beyond repair please let me know and I'll delete it until I think I can phrase it correctly.

Comment: You're juggling between models and theories. Are you just asking what things ZFC+(large cardinals) proves about the surreals that ZFC alone doesn't?

Comment: @NoahSchweber Thanks for the heads up, I'll pull out Chang/Keisler and try to fix my terminology. I was under the impression that large cardinal assumptions introduced for category-theoretic purposes might also introduce new surreal numbers and/or new structural properties for the surreals that weren't there before, and I would like to be able to study the surreals that 'existed' before as well as the 'new' ones and be able to delineate between the two.

Comment: @AndreasBlass Part of the reason I believed that new cardinal assumptions meant new surreals was your answer here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/125354/surreal-numbers-and-large-cardinals.  Am I misinterpreting what you said?

Comment: "new cardinal assumptions meant new surreals" Again, you're mixing up models and theories. Theories are appropriate for proving statements, and asking what sorts of things ZFC+(large cardinals) proves about the surreals which ZFC alone doesn't is perfectly meaningful. If you want to compare the *literal objects*, you need to be working with specific *models*. So, for example, one reasonable way to phrase your question would be: "If $M$ is an inner model of $N$, and $N$ satisfies [large cardinal axiom] and $M$ doesn't, how do $Surreals^M$ and $Surreals^N$ compare?"

Comment: A larger (Grothendieck) universe will have more surreal numbers. But that doesn't necessarily mean that the properties of these two surreal number systems will be different.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Let me add to your comment (which I just upvoted) that it will be important what operations and predicates one considers in the surreal number system. If one uses only the algebraic structure, then the system's properties are completely described by saying "real closed field". At the other extreme, with enough structure on the system of surreals, one should be able to interpret the whole set-theoretic universe in it. I don't know (but experts probably do) whether the algebraic structure plus "birthdays" suffices for this.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Thank for your patience and advice, I've (hopefully) edited the question to make it meaningful.

Comment: @AndreasBlass Thank you for clarifying, this is exactly what I would like to know; when will the larger (Grothendieck) universe have surreals with different properties?

Comment: By "model of ZFC" do you mean a set model or a possibly a proper class model?

Comment: @Qfwfq A possibly proper class one is what I had in mind, although I would be interested to hear about the set-only case too.

Comment: You do not obtain new cardinals and ordinals in general, that is a bad misunderstanding. For instance, if there is a measurable, then the inner model $L$ has the same ordinals as $V$ and *more* cardinals.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo That is fascinating, thank you for the correction; could you explain roughly how this happens in the space of a comment, or is there perhaps somewhere I can read more about how/when this happens?

Comment: Jech's *Set theory* text is a good reference.

Comment: @AlecRhea Briefly, cardinal-ness is a $\Pi_1$ property: $\alpha$ is a cardinal if a certain thing *doesn't* exist (namely, a surjection onto $\alpha$ from a smaller ordinal). Remember that $\Pi_1$ principles are **downwards absolute**: if $N$ is a model of ZFC and $M$ is a relatively transitive submodel of $N$, then every $N$-cardinal is an $M$-cardinal but not necessarily conversely. For example, if there is a measurable cardinal (and this is massive overkill) then $\omega_1^L$ is actually countable.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Ah, so we may delete some of the surjections in a submodel and make it think more ordinals are cardinals, this makes perfect sense, thank you.

Comment: Do you have examples of algebraic/topologic/analytic properties of the class of surreal numbers that may be subject to change depending on the properties of the universe?

Comment: @nombre The value class of the surreals getting 'larger' was the only immediately apparent consequence I saw -- their value class is an abelian totally ordered group containing all the cardinals, so if we add some weakly compact ones it should be 'larger' in a precise sense.  Other than this no, and I am not really satisfied with this example since it's pretty much a direct translation of the large cardinal axiom.

Comment: @nombre Although you've pointed out before that the surreals are isomorphic to their own value class as an ordered additive group, so I'm not even really sure I've said anything beyond re-observing that 'there is a weakly compact cardinal'.

Comment: I was rather thinking about fields $\mathbf{No}(\kappa)$ for certain large cardinals $\kappa$, but I see you are more interested in the whole class of surreal numbers, which might be less affected by large cardinal properties of the universe. The thing is, the surreal numbers are provably not very special as a topological ordered field, so it's unclear what could be gained from adding cardinals.

Comment: @nombre But how about as a universal $H$-field (https://arxiv.org/abs/1512.02267), or eventually with more analytical structure?  There are manifolds with homeomorphic but not diffeomorphic copies, so 'topological boringness' of some structure doesn't necessarily mean it's analytically trivial, which is the direction I'd like to head in. Incidentally, how might ${\bf No}(\kappa)$ be more affected than all the surreals? (also how are you topologizing the full surreals, since they can't be a member of their own topology without some hyper-class type structure? $\xi$-topologies?)

Comment: Thinking about it, I think my idea that $\mathbf{No}$ might be less affected by large cardinal properties is false since any consistent large cardinal property in ZFC can be transfered as a property of $\mathbf{Ord}$ in **AST** (Ackermann set theory).  I'd say **AST** is a good theory to deal with the order topology on $\mathbf{No}$. 
I don't know how the large cardinal properties of $\mathbf{Ord}$ relate to the large cardinals it may contain so I don't know whether it is better to look at $\mathbf{No}$ in specific universes or at $\mathbf{No}(\kappa)$ for some large cardinal $\kappa$.

Comment: As for the analytic properties of $\mathbf{No}$ equipped with additionnal structure, I guess they might be affected as well but it is hard to tell since it is unclear what "the analytical structure of $\mathbf{No}$" is. I would guess that the first order properties of $\mathbf{No}(\kappa)$ equipped with a model-theoretically tamed structure (such as its structure of valued differential field) will be the same for any uncountable cardinal $\kappa$ and even for a family of large countable ordinals.

Comment: @nombre Your insight is appreciated as always -- also, after posting that Aschenbrenner/Dries/Hoeven paper above I realized you first showed it to me (inadvertently) in another post :).