# Simple transfinite generalization of $p$-adic integers

Tags: power-series, ordinal-numbers, p-adic-numbers

One way to define the ring of $p$-adic integers is as a quotient of the formal power series semiring $\Bbb N[[x]]/(x-p)$. One can likewise start with the formal power series ring $\Bbb Z[[x]]/(x-p)$ and get the same result.

It's fairly easy to see why these definition yields the right ring; it is basically equivalent to creating the ring of formal power series (which allows for infinite formal sums in powers of $x$, and then sets $x=p$).

We can replace either of the above with commutative ordinals using natural addition and multiplication, which I will just call $\textbf{Ord}$. In the first situation, we use this semiring to get $\textbf{Ord}[[x]]/(x-p)$. In the second situation, we can use the Grothendieck ring of this semiring, $K[\textbf{Ord}]$, to get the ring $K[\textbf{Ord}][[x]]/(x-p)$.

In both cases $p$ can be any ordinal, even $\omega$  or anything else.

**My questions:**

1. With the naturals and integers, the two definitions yield the same result for any $p \neq 0$. That is, even if you only start with the naturals, after taking the quotient, you get negative numbers anyway as infinite formal sums of natural numbers. For which $p$, if any, do the two definitions yield the same result for $\textbf{Ord}[[x]]/(x-p)$ and $K[\textbf{Ord}][[x]]/(x-p)$?
2. In general, for which $p$, if any, is $\textbf{Ord}[[x]]/(x-p)$ a ring, and not just a semiring?
3. Does the situation change if the exponents of the formal power series are likewise allowed to be arbitrary ordinals, rather than naturals only?
4. Likewise, we allow for a finite amount of negative exponents, can we get a transfinite field of p-adic numbers?
5. Have these constructions been studied in any way?

Basically, I am wondering if there is an answer to this simple metaphor:

- naturals : p-adics :: ordinals : _______

and if something like this is that answer. Much like p-adic numbers allow for countably infinite formal sums of powers of $p$, this extends the Conway normal form to countably infinite sums.

And indeed we seem to get elements from the field of fractions of ordinals, at least in the Grothendieck ring version. For instance, the infinite sum $S = 1 + \omega + \omega^2 + \omega^3 + ...$ would be an element in this ring, and we have $\omega \cdot S + 1 = S$ in both versions of the formal power series. In the Grothendieck ring version, we can further identify $S = \frac{1}{1-\omega}$.

Comment: If $ε$ is an ordinal such that $ω^ε=ε$, then the Grothendieck ring of $ε$ under the natural operations, is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}[(t_ι)_{ι<ε}]$ by identifying $t_ι$ with $ω^{ω^ι}$ (this is clear by Cantor normal form). Ditto for $\mathbb{N}[(t_ι)_{ι<ε}]$ without “Grothendieck ring”. Using the class $\mathbf{Ord}$ for $ε$ does nothing but decrease generality and make things more painful to speak about ([see this discussion](https://mathoverflow.net/a/322596/17064)). …

Comment: …So you should probably remove ordinals from the picture and ask the purely algebraic question of whether $\mathbb{Z}[(t_i)][[x]]/(x-p)$ and $\mathbb{N}[(t_i)][[x]]/(x-p)$ have a simpler description in relation to $\mathbb{Z}_p[(t_i)]$ and $\mathbb{Z}_p[[(t_i)]]$. (Probably something like power series whose coefficients tend to $0$ in a suitable sense. I didn't give this much thought.)

Comment: On the other hand, if you want to mix $p$-adics and ordinals, you may be interested in Hahn series and their Witt-twisted variation: see Kedlaya, “Power Series and $p$-Adic Algebraic Closures” (*J. Number Theory* **89** (2001) 324–339) and other papers of the same author that it cites or which cite it, or Poonen's survey “Maximally complete fields” (*Enseign. Math.* **39** (1993) 87–106).